Create "libs" folder for Expo (Android) without Ejecting
I currently need to integrate an SDK in my Expo project, for Android.
According to the SDK Manual, I need to create a "libs" folder in the Root of the project und put an .aar file in there.
However, in Expo, the analogous root folder would be the "android" folder, which only appears after ejecting the expo project, right? However, I don't want to eject as I want to keep the managed workflow.
Is there a way to create such a folder in the same folder as the build.gradle without ejecting the project? I already managed to change the build.gradle without ejecting, by using config plugins.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Adding the Android folder to your project is as easy as executing the following command.

$   npx expo prebuild --platform android

The --platform android flag is not necessary but then it will create an Android & iOS folder.
Make sure you follow the documentation of Expo

Thank you, but the documentation you linked says that one should not modify this directory: "If you modify the generated directories manually then you risk losing your changes the next time you run npx expo prebuild --clean. Instead, you should use config plugins — functions that perform modifications on native projects during prebuild."
